# TypeError: sessions.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Pretty much new to Nodejs and I'm learning it using one of the courses on pluralsight. I have written below code as part of the course, but i'm stuck with an error and can't continue the course.

**Error :**

```
> TypeError: C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research
> UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\src\views\Sessions.ejs:125
>     123|       <div class="container">
> 
>     124| 
> 
>  >> 125|         <% sessions.map((session, index)=>{%>
> 
>     126|             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 adj_text">
> 
>     127| 
> 
>     128|               <h3><%=session.title%></h3>
> 
> 
> sessions.map is not a function
>     at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research
> UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12),
> <anonymous>:12:17)
>     at Sessions (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
>     at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
>     at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
>     at View.render (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
>     at tryRender (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
>     at Function.render (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
>     at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research
> UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
>     at file:///C:/Users/thota01/OneDrive%20-%20Cancer%20Research%20UK/Desktop/Thota/Learning/WebSite_Nodejs/app.js:32:13
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\thota01\OneDrive - Cancer Research
> UK\Desktop\Thota\Learning\WebSite_Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

**Code**
**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const sessions = require('./src/data/sessions.json');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const sessionsRouter = express.Router();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('views','./src/views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');

sessionsRouter.route('/')
    .get((req,res)=>{
        res.render('Sessions',{sessions,
    });
    });

    sessionsRouter.route('/:id')
    .get((req,res)=>{
        const id = req.params.id;
        res.render('Sessions',{
            sessions:sessions[id],
        });
    });

app.use('/Sessions', sessionsRouter);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index',{title:'Globomantics',data:['a','b','c']});
});

app.listen(PORT,()=> {
    console.log(`listening on port number ${chalk.green(PORT)}`);
});
```

**Sessions.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Globomantics</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style-home.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/G.png" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-8">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Globo-Logo-white.svg" alt="logo" /></a><span class="text">MANIACALLY
            TAKING TECH TO THE GLOBE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-togle col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" id="hamburger" class="navbar-toggle x collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbar-collapse-x">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-x">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                  <div class="search1">
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Search">
                  </div>
                </li>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="our-story.html">Our story<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="sessions">Sessions</a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="robotics.html">Robotics</a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="media.html">Media</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Support</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- .navbar-collapse -->
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="right_section col-md-5 col-xs-12">
          <div class="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> <input type="text" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="our-story.html">Our story<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="sessions">Sessions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="robotics.html">Robotics</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="media.html">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-in col-md-2">
          <span class="dvider"></span>
          <div class="sign">
            <a hrf="#"><img class="sign-in-img" src="images/avatar.svg" alt="sign-in">
              Sign-in</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="sec_include">
      <div class="container">
        <% sessions.map((session, index)=>{%>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 adj_text">
              <h3><%=session.title%></h3>
              <p><%=session.description.slice(0,300)%></p>
                <a href="/sessions/<%=index%>" class="btn-oval">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
  </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="main-footer col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="foter-logo col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
            <a href="index.html"><img class="desktop" src="images/Globo-Logo-white-footer.svg"><img class="mobileImg"
                src="images/G.png">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="links col-md-5 col-md-5 col-xs-10">
            <ul class="quick-links col-md-4 col-xs-6">

              <li><a href="our-story.html">Our Story</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
              <li><a href="robotics.html">Robotics</a></li>
              <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="quick-links second-row col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Media Inquiries</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---container-->
      <div class="video-sec col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="video-heading text-center"><img src="images/pluralsight-white.png"></h1>
        <span class="border"></span>
        <p class="footer-p">This site is created for demonstrative purposes only and does not offer any real products or
          services.
        <p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!---------- End of Wrapper ----------->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

      // alert("wow");
      //  jQuery("header").addClass("fixed");
      jQuery("#hamburger").click(function () {
        //alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        jQuery("header").toggleClass("fixed");
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show a sample of `sessions.json`.

Comment: You're trying to reference `sessions` as an array in your template, but you're passing this to the template:  `sessions:sessions[id]` so, sessions available to the template is a specific session, not an array.

Comment: **session.json**
[
        {
           "id":84473,
           "title":"Secure Programming for the Enterprise",
           "description":"Est sunt nostrud.",
           "startsAt":"8:00",
           "endsAt":"5:00",
           "speakers":[
              {
                 "id":"2bda8276-b7b6-4653-a7c5-1bcc59d11a49",
                 "name":"Jean Ryan"
              }
           ],
           "room":"Europa",
           "day":"Wednesday",
           "format":"FullDay Workshop",
           "track":".NET",
           "level":"Intermediate"
        }
     ]

Comment: @user14932992 I have posted an answer. Try that and tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Your session.json is a *single Object* **NOT** and *array of objects*. So you can't loop over them.

Here is what it looks:

```js
[
   {
      "id":84473,
      "title":"Secure Programming for the Enterprise",
      "description":"Est sunt nostrud.",
      "startsAt":"8:00",
      "endsAt":"5:00",
      "speakers":[
         {
            "id":"2bda8276-b7b6-4653-a7c5-1bcc59d11a49",
            "name":"Jean Ryan"
         }
      ],
      "room":"Europa",
      "day":"Wednesday",
      "format":"FullDay Workshop",
      "track":".NET",
      "level":"Intermediate"
   }
]
```

In your template you are trying to loop over them simply do:

```html
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 adj_text">

   <h3><%=sessions.title%></h3>

   <p><%=sessions.description.slice(0,300)%></p>

       <a href="/sessions/0" class="btn-oval">Learn More</a>
  </div>
```

But if you want to pass an array from the server as well as render a single session:

```html
<% if(sessions.length > 0) { %>
   <% sessions.map((session, index)=>{%>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 adj_text">
              <h3><%=session.title%></h3>
              <p><%=session.description.slice(0,300)%></p>
                <a href="/sessions/<%=index%>" class="btn-oval">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
<% } else { %>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 adj_text">
              <h3><%=sessions.title%></h3>
              <p><%=sessions.description.slice(0,300)%></p>
                <a href="/sessions/0" class="btn-oval">Learn More</a>
            </div>
<% } %>
```

Simply check the length **before** actually looping through them to avoid any issues.

Hope this solves your problem.